# vector<double> find double within tolerance level

Tags: c++, vector, stl, find

I have a

```
std::vector<double> v;
```

I'm looking to detect the presence of a real value in it, up to a error tolerance level of say

```
 1e-6;
```

[The documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) indicates the `operator==` is used to find the presence of value in the container.

How do I generate the behaviour I require on doubles ?

Comment: Use `find_if` with a custom predicate.

Comment: thanks -- this will do the trick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use plain `find` to search with a custom comparator - you need to use `find_if` instead. You have an answer for C++11 already, here's one for use with C++03:

```
struct dbl_cmp {
    dbl_cmp(double v, double d) : val(v), delta(d) { }
    inline bool operator()(const double &x) const {
        return abs(x-val) < delta;
    }
private:
    double val, delta;
};
...
find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), dbl_cmp(10.5, 1E-8));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can approach it like this.

```
double a=3.14;  // The value you seek
std::find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[a](double b) { return abs(a - b) < epsilon; });
```

The floating point folks will likely have a better equivalence comparison approach than what I've offered here.

Comment: I think it's commonly written as `abs(a - b) < epsilon`.